# collecting guides in patchwork not working for two grid faceted ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I'm trying to add two ggplots that have used facet_grid together and collect the guides for the colouring underneath. It seems to only be collecting the guide from the second plot and even when I try to turn off the guide in the first plot it is still shown as a duplicate

Managed to replicate the error here
[image]

with this code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
n <- 100
data <- data.frame(
  plot_label = c(rep("A", n), rep("B", n)),
  facet_x = sample(c("p", "q", "r"), 2*n, replace = TRUE),
  facet_y = sample(1:5, 2*n, replace = TRUE),
  colour = sample(c("x", "y", "z"), 2*n, replace = TRUE),
  random_x = runif(2*n),
  random_y = rnorm(2*n)
)

p1 <- data %>%
  filter(plot_label == "A") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = random_x, y = random_y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = colour)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("purple", "skyblue", "green"), name = "myscale") +
  facet_grid(facet_x~facet_y)
p2 <- data %>%
  filter(plot_label == "B") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = random_x, y = random_y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = colour)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("purple", "skyblue", "green"), name = "myscale") +
  facet_grid(facet_x~facet_y)
plot <- (p1 + p2) &
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") & 
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom", 
    legend.key.size = unit(0.2, "cm"), 
    legend.title = element_text(size = 16),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12)
    )
plot
```

If necessary, I could probably also facet by the splitting variable ("A" and "B") but would greatly prefer not to for reasons to do with the real world use case.

I've only been using patchwork when putting together plots for this piece of work, so a reasonable chance I'm missing something basic but I cant for the life of me work it out

Comment: If you replace `& plot_layout(guides = "collect")` with `+ plot_layout(guides = "collect")` it should work I think.

Comment: ahh I feel very stupid! is there a good reference of when to use & vs +? I havent come across one and a google for patchwork operators returns nothing. But it works :+1:

Comment: It is documented at `?patchwork::plot_arithmetic`, but roughly `+` means append a plot or layout whereas `&` means apply to all underlying plots recursively. Probably `+ plot_layout()` was easier to implement due to operator precedence or for some other reason.